# Trying to link tables with SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to link two tables on phpMYadmin using sql so that the "cuisineid" is the same on both tables

at the moment this is the code im using at the moment

```
INSERT INTO`recipename`
SELECT`Nation`.cuisineid 
FROM`Nation`
INNER JOIN`recipename`
ON`Nation`.cuisineid=`recipename`.cuisineid
```

this is the error i'm getting..

#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: does recipename only have 1 column?

Comment: The answer is in the error message itself. Have you read the manual on [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html)?

Comment: I've been reading up on it today, (this is for a university project) and followed how to do the join form w3schools, recipe name has got 11 columns but Nation only has 2

Comment: See the answer given below then. It should shed some light on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table `recipename` must have more than one column.

Either you intended to select more columns to insert; for example if `recipename` has 4 columns:

```
INSERT INTO `recipename`
SELECT `Nation`.cuisineid, someColumn, 'foo', someOtherColumn, 'bar'
FROM `Nation`
INNER JOIN `recipename`
ON `Nation`.cuisineid = `recipename`.cuisineid
```

Or perhaps you meant to specify a column list, telling which column the data is for (other columns will get their default value):

```
INSERT INTO `recipename` (cuisineid)
SELECT `Nation`.cuisineid
FROM `Nation`
INNER JOIN `recipename`
ON `Nation`.cuisineid = `recipename`.cuisineid
```

Comment: recipename has 11 columns in total,
so will give that second option a try

Comment: you solved it cheers mate got to wait a couple of minutes before i can accept your answer!